# Why not delete objects from Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform

[This answer from Parse](https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-delete-object) says:

> You can call destroy() on any ParseObject from Cloud Code to delete them. Deleting, as well as creating or updating, multiple objects from Cloud Code is not recommended, however.

Why? The answerer doesn't say, and it seems like Cloud Code would be exactly the place to bulk update/delete objects. Is he using Cloud Code in opposition to a Cloud background job? Or am I missing some other way to delete objects in Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer was from before the launch of Background Jobs, which have an increased time-limit.

Cloud Functions have a 15 second maximum run-time.  This is why you need to be a little conservative about how many operations you perform in a specific cloud function.

Now, Background Jobs are the recommended path for maintenance-type processes.  https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs

They have a 15 minute time limit, and if you're clever about it, can be used to handle lots of work at near-real-time speeds.  i.e. https://gist.github.com/gfosco/131974d200c5e9fc6c94

Comment: This makes sense, although my understanding is that "Cloud Code" includes both Cloud functions and background jobs... no?